# How to restrict multiple login for one user Id?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have created a REST application. In this user can register and login. I have a problem like If A user login with a desktop-1 with there credential and same user login with same credential with desktop-2. I have to restrict the user to access account. Means if user login with desktop-2 the I have to logout desktop-1 account.

How can I achieve this using spring security?
Can I make this with JWT Filter configuration or Session management with spring security?

Is there any other way to handle my scenario?

Comment: Your requirement could be fulfilled by using a `Concurrent Session Filter`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/session-mgmt.html

Comment: Can you please share your security configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Your question in about spring with JWT.  You want to enforce users to login only with 1 device.

I faced the same issue (not with spring but with node-express server , but the solution is general purpose , can be implemented by any language with any framework). The reason you are facing the issue is due to JWT.

JWT is stateless , so server have no idea how many users and on which devices they saved JWT tokens . Server can only verify the JWT , but can not enforce users  only use it in a specific device. To achieve this you have to keep track of  all JWTs ( issue to which user and when  )in your server , which is indeed against JWT principles of stateless architecture.

What can be the solution is that :(which I also implemented after many research) :

do not use JWT for these type of application where user session should be restricted by device no.
Istead use random  tokens on inmemory db like redis. For a single user ,create a random token and send it via http-only cookie to the client if login success and save it in redis like db. Then every time the user will send request  ,you will receive cookie automatically , then you can check the cookie with redis or other in-memory db ,if such cookie exists and matched , means user is authentic.

If user try to login again , there will be already pre existing token in the redis db , so you can send response to the user showing message " logout from the previous device" or you can change the token so the user can not be authenticated for requests send from  older device .

** Special note : I used redis , that does not mean you have to use the same , you can use other in memory dbs , also general database will also work like mongodb , MySQL or Pgsql etc. But these traditional db querying took extra time (latency issue) which can cause extra response time overheads. In-memory dbs are fast as accessing RAM is quite faster .